# Word document content not showing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I created my document in Microsoft Office Word and saved it.

It's size is about 1.5MB, but after opening, there's no content!

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Upload your document (Dropbox, OneDrive etc.) for examination.

Comment: Please try to [clear all text formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clear-all-text-formatting-c094c4da-7f09-4cea-9a8d-c166949c9c80): go to Home tab, click Clear All Formatting in the Font group.